# Why am I getting a Run-Time Error 1004 (Application-defined or Object-defined error) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to run the Macros, I get a **run-time error 1004 (Application-defined or Object-defined error)**, and this line is highlighted.
The line is supposed to populate information in a group of cells from text entered in previous cells. I have double checked the example I'm using and it matches exactly so I'm unsure of the problem.

```
'Places values in WO Row
.Cells(WORow, WOCol).Value = .Range(.Cells(15, WOCol).Value).Value
```

Comment: What is the value of `WORow, WOCol`? And also the value of `.Cells(15, WOCol).Value`  as well? Does that cell have address of another range?

Comment: I'm *guessing* you don't want the `.Range`. Otherwise, either `.Cells(15, WOCol).Value` is not a valid range reference, or `WORow` or `WOCol` are not valid row or column numbers.